# How to recode missing genotype code is " '-' " in the ped file of plink

Tags: imputation, genetics

I'm trying to impute genotype data from the public reference panels but my files fail the file sanity check on Sanger Imputation server and it gives the following error:

```
failed sanity check :

    of Non-ACGTN alternate allele at 1:4635556 .. REF_SEQ:'(null)' vs VCF:'-'
```

I have tried fixing this in the plink with the following command `./plink --bfile chr1 --recode vcf --out chr1_vcf --missing-genotype` -
but then it gives error  Underscore(s) present in sample IDs.
`--recode vcf to chr1_vcf.vcf` ... done.
but I still see '_' in the new coded file.

I would appreciate any help, suggestions and comments.

Thanks
Jasdeep

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace `_` with a different character in your `PLINK` files before running your code.

See below from `PLINK` manual

When using `--recode` vcf, sample IDs are formed by merging the `FID` and `IID` and placing an underscore between them. When the `FID` or `IID` already contains an underscore, this may make it difficult to reconstruct them from the VCF file; you may want to replace underscores with a different character in `PLINK` files (`Unix tr` is handy here).